# Apache Tika exclude some html tags

Tags: python, apache-tika

I am testing Apache Tika REST Api via [python](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python) for parsing HTML files. Everything works except one thing. Interior of `<noscript>` tags is also parsed as text and I am having some css styling content in my text, which is undesirable. Also, body of  `<div style="display:none">` is extracted as well. Is there a way to blacklist some html tags in the Tika rest API?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an immediate solution, but the request seems reasonable so please open an issue on our JIRA for the team to discuss: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TIKA/summary

Comment: Is the solution available now with the latest version of tika? @Tim Allison 

I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2805 .  Ping that issue and see if you can get some attention...